# Apache doesn't release ram

Tags: php, linux, apache, centos, typo3

I have a strange behavior from a CentOS 7 vm which is running a pretty basic lamp configuration:

- Apache 2.4.6 (MPM worker)
- MySQL 5.7 (Percona Server 5.7)
- php 7.2 (with php-fpm)

I have other vm/instances with this kind of configuration and they run pretty well without any of the problems I'm experiencing with this one.

Basically on the vm runs a single TYPO3 site used as a content crawler for another site running on other servers, the problem I'm experiencing is frequent OOMs with Apache using all the vm ram and not releasing any of this ram, even if there are no more http requests.

This is an example of this vm state every morning.

```
 [root@drakaris ~]#free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7820        7489         132          37         198          79
Swap:          1023         752         271

 [root@drakaris ~]#ps_mem
 Private  +   Shared  =  RAM used       Program

  8.0 KiB +  25.0 KiB =  33.0 KiB       agetty (2)
  4.0 KiB +  43.5 KiB =  47.5 KiB       systemd-udevd
  4.0 KiB +  97.5 KiB = 101.5 KiB       dhclient
 92.0 KiB +  65.0 KiB = 157.0 KiB       gssproxy
132.0 KiB +  36.0 KiB = 168.0 KiB       irqbalance
164.0 KiB +  43.0 KiB = 207.0 KiB       crond
140.0 KiB +  86.5 KiB = 226.5 KiB       master
144.0 KiB +  85.5 KiB = 229.5 KiB       qmgr
188.0 KiB +  57.5 KiB = 245.5 KiB       auditd
196.0 KiB +  61.5 KiB = 257.5 KiB       lvmetad
256.0 KiB +  79.5 KiB = 335.5 KiB       chronyd
588.0 KiB +  63.5 KiB = 651.5 KiB       systemd-logind
620.0 KiB +  90.5 KiB = 710.5 KiB       dbus-daemon
612.0 KiB + 137.0 KiB = 749.0 KiB       su
704.0 KiB +  67.5 KiB = 771.5 KiB       cvfwd
548.0 KiB + 256.0 KiB = 804.0 KiB       cvlaunchd
620.0 KiB + 261.5 KiB = 881.5 KiB       rsyslogd
588.0 KiB + 315.5 KiB = 903.5 KiB       tuned
932.0 KiB + 111.5 KiB =   1.0 MiB       polkitd
  1.1 MiB + 124.5 KiB =   1.2 MiB       pickup
  1.1 MiB + 184.5 KiB =   1.3 MiB       sudo
  1.5 MiB + 104.0 KiB =   1.6 MiB       bash (2)
  1.0 MiB + 592.5 KiB =   1.6 MiB       zabbix_agentd (6)
148.0 KiB +   1.5 MiB =   1.7 MiB       php-fpm (6)
  1.3 MiB + 570.5 KiB =   1.9 MiB       ClMgrS
664.0 KiB +   1.7 MiB =   2.3 MiB       sshd (3)
  3.0 MiB + 229.0 KiB =   3.3 MiB       systemd-journald
  2.3 MiB +   1.2 MiB =   3.5 MiB       collectd
  3.5 MiB + 124.0 KiB =   3.7 MiB       systemd
  5.6 MiB + 731.0 KiB =   6.4 MiB       cvd
 80.4 MiB + 151.5 KiB =  80.5 MiB       mysqld
  7.0 GiB +  17.9 MiB =   7.0 GiB       httpd (4)
---------------------------------
                          7.1 GiB
=================================

 [root@drakaris ~]#smem -pt
  PID User     Command                         Swap      USS      PSS      RSS
  560 root     /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-ud    0.23%    0.00%    0.00%    0.00%
 1029 root     /sbin/dhclient -1 -q -lf /v    0.20%    0.00%    0.00%    0.00%
 1519 root     /sbin/agetty --noclear tty1    0.01%    0.00%    0.00%    0.00%
 1521 root     /sbin/agetty --keep-baud 11    0.01%    0.00%    0.00%    0.00%
... [SNIP]
16500 root     sudo su -                      0.00%    0.01%    0.02%    0.02%
 1452 root     /opt/commvault/Base/ClMgrS     1.25%    0.02%    0.02%    0.03%
  517 root     /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-jo    0.59%    0.04%    0.04%    0.05%
 1503 root     /usr/sbin/collectd             0.22%    0.03%    0.04%    0.06%
    1 root     /usr/lib/systemd/systemd --    0.09%    0.05%    0.05%    0.05%
 1449 root     /opt/commvault/Base/cvd       13.52%    0.07%    0.08%    0.09%
18027 root     python /bin/smem -pt           0.00%    0.13%    0.13%    0.14%
16878 mysql    /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemoniz   30.91%    1.03%    1.03%    1.03%
13401 apache   /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUN    0.97%   38.66%   38.76%   38.88%
10914 apache   /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUN   18.10%   52.77%   52.87%   52.99%
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   50 9                                      82.97%   92.94%   93.20%   93.66%
```

If a simply do an Apache restart the ram is released and everything came back to a normal idle state.

I thought it could be some memory leak from TYPO3 but I can't check it because I have no access to it, but I would like to find why Apache keeps all this ram occupied apparently for no reason, and in case I'll find some clue about TYPO3 I will submit them to the project owner for a solution.

Do you think it's possible to dump some data from those Apache processes to find out why it's using all this ram for all this time?

Comment: https://www.tecmint.com/improve-php-fpm-performance/

Comment: @bassxzero in my case there's no sign of php-fpm eating memory, almost all memory is used by Apache processes.

Comment: I have not seen this behaviour, what I would expect is that php-fpm eats memory if problem TYPO3 related, perhaps this helps: https://serverfault.com/questions/594624/apache-2-2-eventually-using-all-memory-worker-mpm

Comment: Also, perhaps consider mpm "event" instead of "worker"